# Google Places autocomplete waypoints with text input arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps

I have built a form with dynamic array for a text input called `waypoints[]`. I need to give my form text inputs access to my Google Places autocomplete (which already works for my non array text inputs).

This is what I have:

JavaScript:

```js
function initialize() {
    var options = {
        componentRestrictions: {
           country: "au"
        }
    };

    var inputs = document.getElementById('start');
    var autocompletes = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputs, options);
    var inpute = document.getElementById('end');
    var autocompletee = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inpute, options);

    for (var i = 0; i < waypoints.length; i++) {
        var inputw = document.getElementById(waypoints[i]);
        var autocompletew = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputw, options);
    }

    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var melbourne = new google.maps.LatLng(-31.953512, 115.857048);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: melbourne
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="dynamicInput">
      <br>1<input type="text" name="waypoints[]" autocomplete="on">
</div>
<input type="button" value="Another Delivery" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
```

As it is, the "start" and "end" works fine, but the `waypoints[]` do not. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<input>` for the waypoints has no id, you can't get a reference to it with `document.getElementById`.  You need to do something like:

```
var waypoints = document.getElementsByName("waypoints[]");
for (var i = 0; i < waypoints.length; i++) {
    var inputw = waypoints[i];
    var autocompletew = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputw, options);
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/v5sh9o2z/1/)